# Proving that $ (\mathbb E [X^n])^{1/n}\leq (\mathbb E [X^m])^{1/m}$ for $1\leq X\leq 2 \ \mathbb P \text{-a.e.}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

How to prove that for a positive essentially bounded random variable $X$ satisfing $1\leq X\leq 2 \  \mathbb P \text{-a.e.}$ and for any $m,n \in \mathbb N^*$ with $m\geq n$ we have 
$$ (\mathbb E [X^n])^{1/n}\leq (\mathbb E [X^m])^{1/m}.$$

It's very simple to see that 
$$ \mathbb E [X^n]\leq \mathbb E [X^m]$$
since $m/n \geq 1 $ and $X\geq 1 $. Still by monotonicity of $x \rightarrow x^{1/n}$ it holds that 
$$ (\mathbb E [X^n])^{1/n}\leq (\mathbb E [X^m])^{1/n}$$
or
$$ (\mathbb E [X^n])^{1/m}\leq (\mathbb E [X^m])^{1/m}$$

How can we conclude from there ? There is a better alternative approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jensen may help.

Comment: And the hypothesis that $1\leqslant X\leqslant2$ can be omitted.